# Can't Authorize in Swagger with a Minimal API in .NET 7

Tags: c#, jwt, authorization, .net-7.0

I can't use [Authorize] on my endpoints, because they don't work in the Application if I check them in combination with Swagger Authorize. If don't put the [Authorize] on, then everything is working fine in Swagger (because of the [AllowAnonymous]). I put an Authorize button in Swagger to Authorize the endpoints with a JWT Key/Token, when I tag them with [Authorize], then the endpoints give a 401 response. Even if I use the token to Authorize endpoint.

What could be the problem? Thanks in advance...

Token controller

```
app.MapPost("/accounts/login", [AllowAnonymous] (UserDto user) =>
{
    if(user.username == "Winston" && user.password == "Password123")
    {
        // genereer token
        var secureKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"]);

        var issuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"];
        var audience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"];
        var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(secureKey);
        var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512);

        var jwtTokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
            {
                new Claim("Id","1"),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.username),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, user.username),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
            }),
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5),
            Audience = audience,
            Issuer = issuer,
            SigningCredentials = credentials
        };

        var token = jwtTokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
        var jwtToken = jwtTokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
        return Results.Ok(jwtToken);
        
    }
    return Results.Unauthorized();
});
```

Scheme, Swagger and Jwt Authentication

```
var securityScheme = new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
{
    Name =  "Authorisation",
    Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
    Scheme = "Bearer",
    BearerFormat = "JWT",
    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
    Description = "JWT Authentication for MinimalApi"
};

var securityRequirements = new OpenApiSecurityRequirement()
{
    {
        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
           Reference = new OpenApiReference
           {
                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                Id = "Bearer"
           }
        },
        new string[] {}
    }
};

var contactInfo = new OpenApiContact()
{
    Name = "Winston",
    Email = "whmuijs@gmail.com",
    Url = new Uri("https://databrein.online")
};

var license = new OpenApiLicense
{
    Name = "Free License",
};

var info = new OpenApiInfo()
{
    Version = "v1",
    Title = "ToDo list with JWT Authentication",
    Description = "ToDo list with JWT Authentication",
    Contact = contactInfo,
    License = license,

};


builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.SwaggerDoc("v1", info);
    options.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", securityScheme);
    options.AddSecurityRequirement(securityRequirements);
 });

// jwt Authentication

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{ // validatie
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
        ValidateAudience = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"])),
        ValidateLifetime = false, // if not demo: true
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true 
    };
});

builder.Services.AddAuthentication();
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

var app = builder.Build();
```